# What is the approporiate test?

Tags: time-series

I have two variables ; First variable is ordinal and it represent years series from 2006 to 2015 and another variable which is interview score and I want to study if there a relationship between the graduation year and the interview score. What is the appropriate test I shall use ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to CV. It would help your potential respondents if you were to say a bit more about your data. For instance, what is the sample size? What is the unit of analysis? What are the "interviews" about?

Comment: Thank you. My sample size is 34 for a small population (60).

Comment: The interviews are ; Interviews for hiring in a company where each applicant has a degree from 1.00 to 10.00 ( it's included values such as 2.50 etc.)

Comment: A "degree?" Do you mean a *rating* from 1 to 10? What is this a rating of? Candidate's qualifications for a position? Likelihood of future success? What is "graduation year?" Why is the sample size so low? With such a small sample size and large span of years the power of any analysis will be very low.

Comment: Yes . A rating from 1 to 10. Each applicant who apply to a position go thorough three interviews and the score of the interviews will qualify them to be accepted or not for the position.

Answer (score 0):

A Kruskall-Wallis test would be suitable to test, whether ordinal scores are differing between different groups (years). Spearman correlation would be suitable to tell, whether older applicants tend to get higher oder lower scores. (Call that 'ANOVA' and 'Pearson' instead of 'Kruskall-Wallis' and 'Spearman' if you want to deal with problems like normality assumptions in your small sample - hint: you don't want to).